# include other view inside the view

Tags: frameworks, codeigniter-2

I want include in the view some other view parts, like content1,content2,.etc .
Is there a sloution in the Codeigniter, like in Laravel `@yield`.
Sorry if it's dumb question.

Comment: This is a codeigniter question, not laravel related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for that problem, and I would share it.
So in the somepage controller need to the page parts calling separatle, and put it in a array:

```
public function index()
{
        $this->_dataOut['head'] = $this->load->view('head','', TRUE);
        $this->_dataOut['header'] = $this->load->view('layout/header','',TRUE);
        $this->_dataOut['body'] = $this->load->view('publicPages/welcome_message','',TRUE);
        $this->_dataOut['footer'] = $this->load->view('layout/footer','',TRUE);
        $this->_dataOut['foot'] = $this->load->view('foot','',TRUE);
        $this->load->view('mainPage', $this->_dataOut);
}
```

and than we can call the transferred data by the index like this:

```
<?= $head; ?>
<?= $header; ?>
<?= $body; ?>
<?= $footer; ?>
<?= $foot; ?>
```

I hope it helpd some one, or not. :)
I glad to share, have a nice coding day. :)